# Recommended on Sales Dashboard Wordpress Plugin Needed

Tags: wordpress

Im current working in a Property Agency, as i requested to build a dashboard on my wordpress site to show to my company agent the live sales report.

and the same time the result in the dashboard need to link with a google spreadsheet, so the sales admin only required to update the report through google sheet and the dashboard will automatically update and display the result.

So i would like to know is there any recommended wordpress plugin which are suitable for my case?

Thanks

Here is idea dashboard sample that i wanted to create and show on my site
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fNDkGyEslVQDR5oEaXY07PlQKM7Xr1Zs/view?usp=sharing

i look through alot of paid plugin online but doesnt fit my needs.

Comment: So, now you have to customize the plugin as you have mentioned the requirement. you don't get the ready code in free and paid wordpress plugin. Otherwise, you can customize and overwrite the woocommerce functions on product add to cart page

Comment: I have only limited knowledge in customizing a plugin, thats why im looking for a paid plugin

Comment: Are you using the woocommerce plugin??

Comment: Nop, im not using any woocommerce plugin due to my wordpress site just for display purpose for the property. can woocommerce plugin help me to show the similar dashboard?